# Javascript Async Await function requirements

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a project (html + JavaScript) created by other person. There is an image and a button on that html page. When I click the button, it calls a function and processes the image.

My task is to process multiple images using that function. The images must be processed consecutive (not parallel), this is important.

I use Async Await way to call the function, but the 'for loop' does not wait till the function finished processing the first image, it goes to the next images.

I tried to do this different ways (using promises etc.), but it does not work as expected. How can I force the 'for loop' to wait?

```
async function processImages(fileList) {
    for (let file of fileList) {
        await processOneImage(file);
    }            
}

async function processOneImage(filename) {
    // load an image
    document.getElementById('ImageToBeProcessed').src = filename;
    // call the function created by other person
    await document.querySelector('#start_process').click();
}
```

Is there some requirement for the .click() function to work with 'await' in a correct way? For example, .click() does not return anything now. Should I add

```
return someVar
```

to the end of the .click() function?

Or maybe the .click() function should also have 'async' word before 'function'?

I looked at many async/await samples, but it did not help.

Thanks.

P.S. More info:

1. That html+script use Google Polymer (perhaps it is important). I shortened the .click() function code to show you. Now it looks like:

   ```
   this.startProcessButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
       _this.prepareData()
           .then(function () {
           // removed unneeded code here ...
           _this.doProcessing()
           // removed unneeded code here ...
       })
           .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
       });
   });
   ```

As I understand, it is a promise.

2. Unfortunately I can not contact that person. He/she does not answer any questions from Autumn.

Comment: If you want them to run in series (ie, not in parallel) you just want to **not** have the await/async *at all*

Comment: You cannot just click the button and expect it to wait for whatever processing is caused by that. You rather should directly call the processing function that the button handler uses, and you need to make sure that the processing function somehow signals when it's done - it can do that e.g. by returning a promise. Ask the other person for a documentation of the programming interface.

Comment: Thank you. I added P.S. to my question. Please take a look.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#start_process').click()` is an event listener and doesn't return a promise. On the other hand promisifying the event listeners is possible but not a good idea since promises resolve only once but events get triggered multiple times.

Comment: @Redu, I can copy all the code from the click() function to a new function. And then 'promisify' that new function. Will that help? If yes, please suggest how should that function be promisified so it executes 'in series'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to await an operation, it needs to be **async** (or returning a **promise**). Furthermore, when you emit a click on the button, you only execute (and wait for completion) of the click, not the event handler.

You should create a function for processing one image (at the moment your `processOneImage` function doesn't process an image (!), it emits a click on a DOM button):

```
function processOneImage(image) {
    return _this.prepareData()
        .then(function () {
        // removed unneeded code here ...
        _this.doProcessing()
        // removed unneeded code here ...
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

- please note that I've returned the promise!

Then you can have it added to the event listener:

```
this.startProcessButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => processOneImage(getFileNameFromClickEvent(e));
```

- separate your UI related concerns from your processing - `getFileNameFromClickEvent` can help figuring out how to get your file name or other input from the ui

If you have this, you can reuse the `processOneImage` function (awaitable) w/o need of messing with DOM actions and emitting clicks.

```
async function processImages(fileList) {
    for (const file of fileList) {
        await processOneImage(file);
    }            
}
```

Note: this is a quick fix, you should consider following best practices (e.g. not mixing vanilla promises with async/await) and using a modern client framework/lib like React.js.